# How to import a Text File from feeds CSV and map it to a File upload field with multiple values?

Tags: 7, webforms, importing-exporting, feeds

> **EDIT:** This issue is directly related to how the Acquia hosting Platform handles private files, not webforms / feeds or feeds tamper.

I've got a site where I need to Migrate the users from a webform they were using, and convert those submissions into user accounts.

I am using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) (7.x-2.0-beta1+8-dev) and [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) (7.x-4.8) and feeds Tamper.

I've managed to map all the fields except the Attachment field which is of type `File`. The Attachment field has the ability to attach unlimited files. Here are the three options I have when using the **Mapping** section in Feeds importer:

[image]

When I export my CSV from webforms, my Attachment field becomes the parent of every field in my CSV, and won't run until I modify it by removing the Attachment key from the start of the CSV file. (This makes no sense to me.)

After removing the Attachments field I am left with:

> "Email","Name","Filesize (KB)"
>   "testemail@example.com","http://dev.website.ca/system/files/webform/permits/genericfile.txt|http://dev.local488.evsite.ca/system/files/webform/permits/94ufos.txt","55"

In this CSV there is the **Attachment** field and the **Email** field. When the run the CSV import, the user is created but nothing is added to the `file` field. I've tried mapping the **Name** value to all the possible options and it doesn't seem to be outputting anything for me.

When there is multiple values in the **Name** field I am using the `explode` plugin, using `|` as a string separator.
 I'm just not sure if i'm suppose to pass in an array or values or am I missing a module or something? I've browsed several similar questions but they have to do with `Image` i'm just using text files.

**I am just wondering how can I can use the Feeds `User Importer` to import a regular text file from a CSV file and have it uploaded to the `File` widget in the user's Account page?**

Any tips in the right direction are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I can't get to my files is because i'm using the Acquia platform.

Files in `system/files` are aliased from `/mnt/files/[site]dev/sites/[sitename]/files-private`.

By default drupal webforms output the CSV file with: `http://dev.website.ca/system/files/webform/permits/genericfile.txt`

So when I mapped to the `File` field in the profile page, nothing happened because it couldn't find the file.

I did a quick `Ctrl + F` and replaced the `http://dev.website.ca/system/files/` with `/mnt/files/[site]dev/sites/[sitename]/files-private` inside the CSV file.

(you can find your path with `/admin/config/media/file-system`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track from:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1116130#comment-6827626

I believe you to set it to use an array of values (that's what `explode` returns). The file type itself, image vs text file, is largely irrelevant as you simply want it to work with a multiple item field.

Comment: That guys solution was based on having white-space in his `String Separator`. My value for `Name` by default uses `|` as the separator, and I've checked to make sure there was no whitespace. Well if it's as simple as exploding the multivalue then mapping the multivalue field to the URI in the profile then I should be able to figure it out. The files are in the private file system but i can view them so Im not sure if that has anything to do with it